# How to programmatically display a view -- with an "x" button to close the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to programmatically display a view containing an image and an "x" button -- in the code it is labeled *btnDismiss -- to close the view.

Here is my issue:
The code will successfully display the image and the "x" button. However, clicking the "x" button currently doesn't close the view -- Both the image and the "x" button remain visible.

I'm new to xCode, so please provide verbose responses (if you leave out something from your answer, I might not be able to fill in the blanks!)

Note: If you have another solution for how to show an imageView with an "x" button to make both the imageView and the "x" button disappear, that will also be welcome.

Here is my code:

```
#import "XYZViewController.h"

@interface XYZViewController ()

@end

@implementation XYZViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImageView *bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 200)];
    bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage];

    UIButton *btnDismiss = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    [btnDismiss setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDismiss setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnDismiss addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissVC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnDismiss];
}

-(void)dismissVC:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please include the actual issue when asking a question.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it will be clearer to you now.

Comment: Is the `-dismissVC:` method being called? Add a breakpoint to test it out.

Comment: Thank you. I added the break point. Yes, apparently it is being called. 

When testing, I clicked the button and got this error in response: 

Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0xa16edc0> on <XYZViewController: 0x8d38520> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any idea on how to fix this will be welcome.

Comment: Is this `UIViewController` the first View Controller in the app?

Comment: I started from a new Single View Application. I have only added this one View Controller to the app. Otherwise, there is the original XYZViewController which was created with the new project by xCode.

Comment: You get that message because your view controller is not yet on screen, so it can't present other view controllers. Present modally in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is set up to dismiss a view controller that was presented modally. But the views you want to remove are subviews of `self.view`.

You can remove the `UIImageView` and `UIButton` by keeping outlets to them and calling `removeFromSuperview` in your remove method. With this method, you don't need to present or dismiss another view controller.

```
-(void)removeViews:(id)sender {
    [self.xButton removeFromSuperview];
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

#### Edit in response to comment

You'll need to have properties declared for xButton and imageView

```
@property UIButton *xButton;
@property UIImageView *imageView;
```

#### Edit to show full code

```
@interface MJNViewController ()
@property UIButton *xButton;
@property UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation MJNViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 200)];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.xButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
    [self.xButton setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.xButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.xButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeViews:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.xButton];
}

-(void)removeViews:(id)sender
{
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.xButton removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement your solution by moving my UIImageView *bgImage and UIButton *btnDismiss into a method called: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated. I then added your method below and changed the names to self.btnDismiss and self.bgImage. But I got 2 errors: "Property 'btnDismiss' and 'bgImage' not found on object of type "XYZViewController". Not sure what I'm missing here. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't have properties declared for the button and image view. See code updates.

Comment: Thanks again. No errors now. But when testing in the simulator, I click the "x" and the xButton and imageView are still visible. I set a breakpoint so I know that removeViews is being called. For some reason, [self.xButton removeFromSuperview]; and [self.imageView removeFromSuperview]; isn't making imageView and xButton invisible.

Comment: Try it without the breakpoint. The UI won't be updated until the method exits.

Comment: Ok thanks. I removed the breakpoint. Unfortunately, still the same result.

Comment: I added a UIAlertView at the end of the method, and the alert is showing. So the method is definitely getting called.

Comment: Have you actually set the properties?

Comment: Thank you! I modified my code to match your full code and it works perfectly! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another `UIViewController` presenting `XYZViewController` in order for `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:` to work properly.

From the Apple Docs:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.

Since there is no view controller being presented, calling `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:` is not working for you.